# c3p0 thread getting stuck, while executing read query

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle10g, future, c3p0

i am trying to execute multiple read queries parallely. i have used ExecuterService and C3P0 for achieving this scenario. 
now with newFixedThreadPool of executerService as 1, all queries are running normally but sequentially. but with FixedThreadPool > 1, some of the thread are getting stuck indefinitely while executing read query [statement.executeQuery()] until the connection timed-out.the resultSet, PreparredStatement and connection are also getting safely closed after processing ResultSet.

i think there is something very wrong with c3p0 configuration. here is the c3p0 configs -

```
<bean id="parentDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" abstract="true">
    <property name="driverClass" value="amazon.jdbc.driver.SecureDriver" />
    <property name="user" ref="dbusername" />
    <property name="password" ref="dbpassword" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="select 1 from dual" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false" />
    <!-- Pool properties -->
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="40" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="30" />
    <property name="loginTimeout" value="300" />
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="5000"></property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true"></property>
    <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false"></property>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="1000"></property>
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="300"></property>
    <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="1000"></property>
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="7"></property>
    <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="1800"></property>
    <property name="connectionTesterClassName"
        value="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester"></property>
    <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true"></property>
    <property name="maxAdministrativeTaskTime" value="1500"></property>
</bean>
```

any suggessions or help would be greatly appreciated.

code :

```
private static final int POOLSIZE = 5;

private ExecutorService executer = Executors
        .newFixedThreadPool(POOLSIZE);

private List<String> doValidation(
        final ComboPooledDataSource dataSource, final File sqlFolder) {
    List<Future<String>> futureTasks = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> queryResults = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final File sqlFile : sqlFolder.listFiles()) {
        String sqlQuery = readSql(sqlFile);
        Future<String> future = getFutureTask(sqlQuery,
                dataSource);
        if (future != null) {
            futureTasks.add(future);
        }
    }
    queryResults = extractValidationResponceFromFuture(
            futureTasks);
    return queryResults;
}


private Connection getConnection(final ComboPooledDataSource dataSource) {
    try {
        Connection connection = null;
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        return connection;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw(e);
    }
}


private Future<String> getFutureTask(final String sqlQuery, final ComboPooledDataSource dataSource) {
    Callable<String> callable;
    callable = new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            final String queryResult = runSql(sqlQuery, dataSource);
            return queryResult;
        }
    };
    Future<String> future = executer.submit(callable);
    return future;
}

private String readSql(final File sqlFile) {
    // querystring contains the query i.e content of a file
        String queryString = FileUtils.readFileToString(sqlFile);
        return queryString;
}

private List<String> extractValidationResponceFromFuture(
        List<Future<String>> futureTasks) {
    List<String> queryresponces = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Future<String> futureTask : futureTasks) {
        try {
            S3MetaData responce = futureTask.get();
            if (responce != null) {
                queryresponces.add(responce);
            } 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage(),
                    e.getCause());
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage(),
                    e.getCause());
        }
    }
    return queryresponces;
}

private String runSql(final String query,final ComboPooledDataSource dataSource) {
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String outputFilePath = new String();
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {
        dbConnection = getConnection(dataSource);

        statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        String resultFileLoc = putResultInFile(resultSet);
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        throw new SQLException(e);
    } finally {
        DBUtility.safeClose(resultSet, statement,
                dbConnection);
    }
    return resultFileLoc;
}
```

here is safe close code for connection, similarly doing for resultset and prepared statement.

```
public static final void safeClose(final ResultSet resultSet,
        final PreparedStatement statement, final Connection connection) {
    safeClose(resultSet);
    safeClose(statement);
    safeClose(connection);
}

public static final void safeClose(final Connection connection) {
    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("error while closing connection", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to set autoCommitOnClose to true. Please post the code with connection obtaining, executors call, query performing and returning connection. Does your query contain links to remote databases or something non-trivial? Is the behavior the same if the query is simple, e.g. `select 1 from dual`?

Comment: @Qualtagh : i have added code base. and the thread is getting stuck for some of queries always. like out of 5 different queries it will stuck for 3rd one with any poolsize > 1. And the queries does not contain any kind of links into it, the queries are complex or simple select queries, just reading data from multiple joins of tables.

Comment: well, there are too many factors. I'm afraid I can't help you much. Is it some kind of Amazon cloud service? Is there a DB-side limit on allowed connections? If c3p0 pool size is higher than DB limit, the connections would hang. Are you sure (checked by debugging or logging) that the program freezes at `futureTask.get()`? So, `getConnection` and `prepareStatement` are performed normally, only `executeQuery` is stuck, right? The queries are read from files and results are written to files. Isn't the problem in simultaneous access to files?

Comment: Can you check the behavior without c3p0? Only pure JDBC. `Class.forName( "amazon.jdbc.driver.SecureDriver" ); Connection dbConnection = new Connection( "jdbc:oracle:..." ); ...` Is it possible that there are triggers on tables that cause locks? Can you check execution with absolutely simple queries like `select 1 from dual`?

Comment: Are you sure that c3p0 settings are really set when the pool is created? c3p0 has properties like `acquireIncrement` and `acquireRetryAttempts` which may cause hanging. But you don't change them and their default values are normal.

Comment: As I understand, there are no exceptions thrown, right? Please add the code of pool creation and DBUtility.safeClose. We have to be sure that the resources are released properly.

Comment: @Qualtagh : i checked the db limit for max connection and found the db has much higher limit than the c3p0 pool size. and yes "getConnection" and "preparedStatement" are performing normally and only the thread got stuck during "executeQuery". And the queries are doing read and write into different files, so i guess that should not be a problem.

Comment: And yes some of tables are having triggers on it, but those are "insert or update" trigger and should not affect the select or read queries at all as of my understanding. And yes i check the whole thing by running simple query "select 1 from dual" and in this case everything is working fine, nothing got stuck.

Comment: What about pure JDBC? Would it hang on complex queries too?

Comment: @Qualtagh : with pure JDBC connection means, for each query creating new dbConnection ? if yes, then in this case it will work serially, as it is working with poolsize 1.

Comment: and yes, some of queries which got stuck, are not so very complex. ex :    [ select a form A where b in (select c from B) groupby a and orderby a; ] this is very simple query but still it is causing problem.

Comment: Not serially. In thread pool. But instead of retrieving connections from c3p0 connection pool obtain them in oldschool way: new Connection( "jdbc:oracle:..." ).